# document.fonts.load is not a function in jest

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have the following code:

```
document.fonts.load(this.elementFont).then(() => {
            this.function();
        });
```

I am trying to run the jest tests, but they are not going through because of this function.

I tried the following in beforeEach, but it doesn't work:

```
Object.defineProperty(document, 'fonts', {
            value: { load: Promise.resolve({}) },
          })
```

I tried the following also in my code, but doesn't work too:

```
jest.spyOn(global.document.fonts, 'load').mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve([{} as FontFace]))
```